# Can you explain this Embedded MATLAB Function error?

Tags: matlab, embedded, simulink

I'm having a problem sending a value from a GUI to an Embedded MATLAB Function (EMF) in a Simulink model. I get this value from a slider in my GUI and send it to an EMF block in my model. I can confirm that the value is being transferred correctly from my GUI to my Simulink block, since I can display the value with a display block in my model and see the value change when I change the slider position in my GUI. However I keep getting this error when I run my model:

```
Could not determine the size of this expression.

Function 'Kastl' (#18.282.283), line 14, column 1:
"f"
```

This is part of my EMF block code:

```
function y = input_par(u,fstart)
  ...
  f_end = 1000;
  f = fstart:f_end; 
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe [MikeT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259001/matlab-simulink-gui-2/1263797#1263797) is correct: you can't redefine the size of a variable in an embedded function. If you look at this [Embedded MATLAB Function documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f6-106261.html) under the subsection **Defining Local Variables**, it says:

> Once you define a variable, you cannot
>   redefine it to any other type or size
>   in the function body.

You will have to rework your embedded function such that the variables you declare are not changing size. Since I don't know what you are subsequently doing with the variable `f`, there's not much more *specific* help I can give you.

In general, if you *absolutely need* to use data that changes size, one solution is to pad the data with "garbage" values in order to maintain a constant size. For example:

```
MAX_ELEMS = 1000;  % Define the maximum number of elements in the vector
f = [fstart:MAX_ELEMS nan(1,fstart-1)];  % Create vector and pad with NaNs
```

In the above example, the variable `f` will always have 1000 elements (assuming the value of `fstart` is an integer value less than or equal to 1000). The value `NaN` is used to pad the vector to the appropriate constant size. Any subsequent code would have to be able to recognize that a value of `NaN` should be ignored. Depending on what calculations are subsequently done in the embedded function, different pad values might be needed in place of `NaN` (such as 0, negative values, etc.).

Comment: i solved this not with a EMF but with a Level 2 M-file S-Function. for the input, f.e. the fstart i used a Constant- and a Gain-Block which i set from the GUI. And then i used this value for my Level 2 M-file S-Function. It works.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue you are running into is that you can't change a parameter during simulation that will cause the dimension of a signal to change.  In your example, the code,

```
f = fstart:f_end;
```

changes size whenever fstart changes.  I think this is what EMF block is complaining about.  I don't have any easy workaround for this particular issue, but maybe there's an equivalent way of doing what you want that avoids this issue.